# Java regular expression lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I have strings that I need to use regex to replace a specific character. The strings are in the following format:

```
"abc.edf" : "abc.abc", "ghi.ghk" : "bbb.bbb" , "qwq.tyt" : "ddd.ddd"
```

I need to replace the periods, '.', that are between the strings in quotes before the colon but not the strings in quotes after the colon and before the comma. Could someone shed some light?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You must be very close to the solution, since you already noticed lookaheads may help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "with colons"? Can you post example of result after replacing? Also it seems that your answer is in question title, so what is stopping you from using look-around mechanisms?

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will match the entire part that you want to touch: `"\w{3}\.\w{3}" : "\w{3}\.\w{3}"`.  Since it includes the colon and the values on both side, it won't match ones where there is a comma between the values.  Depending on your needs, you may need to change `\w` to some other character class.

But, as I'm sure you are aware, you don't want to replace the entire string.  You only want to replace the one character.  There are two ways to do that.  You can either use look-aheads and look-behinds to exclude everything else except the period from the resulting match:

- Pattern: `(?<="\w{3})\.(?=\w{3}" : "\w{3}\.\w{3}")`
- Replacement: `:`

Or, if the look-aheads and look-behinds confuse you, you could just capture the whole thing and include the original values from the captured groups in the replacement value:

- Pattern: `("\w{3})\.(\w{3}" : "\w{3}\.\w{3}")`
- Replacement: `$1:$2`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But maybe I wasn't being specific. The example up there shows only numbers but they could actually be anything - I was just using numbers to make the illustration simpler. I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following patern: /.(?=[a-z]+)/g

Working regex-demo for substitution @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iB2wP5/1)

### Java Working Demo:

```
public class StackOverFlow31520446 {

    public static String text;
    public static String pattern;
    public static String replacement;

    static {
        text = "\"abc.edf\" : \"123.231\", \"ghi.ghk\" : \"456.678\" , \"qwq.tyt\" : \"141.242\"";
        pattern = "\\.(?=[a-z]+)";
        replacement = ";";
    }

    public static String replaceMatches(String text, String pattern, String replacement) {
        return text.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replaceMatches(text, pattern, replacement));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you intend to do with the string but this is a way to
match the contents of the quote's.

The contents are in capture buffer 1.
You could use a callback to replace the dots within the
contents, passing that back within the main replacement function.

Find:  `"([^"]*\.[^"]*)"(?=\s*:)`
Replace:  `"` + `func( call to replace dots from capt buff 1 )` + `"`

Formatted:

```
 "                             # Open quote
 ( [^"]* \. [^"]* )            # (1), group 1 - contents
 "                             # Close quote
 (?=                           # Lookahead, must be a colon
      \s* 
      :
 )
```

Comment: thanks! this works. could you walk me through the solution?

Comment: @Mozbi - I kind of did in the explanation.  Don't know Java specifically, but find a regex replace all function with a callback capability. The match is passed to the function. Take capture group 1, the contents, replace the dots then pass back a string catenated `"` + new_contents + `"`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If would go for a different approach (maybe it is even faster). In your loop over all strings first try if the string matches a number `\d*\.?\d*` - if not, do the replacement of `.` with `:` (without any regexp).

Would that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without look arounds:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\D)\\.(\\D)", "$1:$2");
```

should be sufficient for the task.

Comment: Won't this replace the periods between numbers?  The OP only wants to replace periods between letters.

Comment: @Shar1er80 yes - not thinking. I've changed the match to "not a digit". thx